# Looking for matches in multi-dimensional arrays inJavascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

I am trying to match entire arrays in Javascript. I have a userInput array and I need to find a matching array within a multi-dimensional array and output the match.

```
var t1 = [0,0,0];
var t2 = [1,0,0];
var t3 = [0,0,1];
var userInput = [0,0,0];
var configs = [t1, t2, t3];
```

I am trying to find a way to match userInput to one of the other arrays and output the matching array.
With underscore.js I can find a match one at a time without looping, but that returns a bool.

```
var result = _.isEqual(userInput,t1) returns true
```

I need to find the matching array inside the configs array.
I can nest loops to go through configs, but I can't figure out how to match it to userInput.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=control) to find the index of the matching config in the array. Use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?v=control) to find the config that is equal.

```js
var t1 = [0,0,0];
var t2 = [1,0,0];
var t3 = [0,0,1];
var userInput = [0,0,1]; // this will fit t3 (index 2)
var configs = [t1, t2, t3];

var result = configs.findIndex(function(arr) {
  return arr.every(function(value, i) {
    return value === userInput[i];
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given input you can use `Array.prototype.find()`, `Array.prototype.toString()` or `Array.prototype.join()`

```js
var t1 = [0,0,0];
var t2 = [1,0,0];
var t3 = [0,0,1];
var userInput = [0,0,0];
var configs = [t1, t2, t3];

var result = configs.find(arr => arr.join() === userInput.join());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control) and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?v=control)

```js
var t1 = [0,0,0];
var t2 = [1,0,0];
var t3 = [0,0,1];
var userInput = [0,0,0];
var configs = [t1, t2, t3];
var inputPresent = configs.some(a => userInput.every((u,i) => a[i] == u));
console.log(inputPresent);
```

If you wanted to know the index of the existing input, you could just include a ternary

```js
var t1 = [0,0,0];
var t2 = [1,0,0];
var t3 = [0,0,1];
var userInput = [0,0,0];
var configs = [t1, t2, t3];
var inputIndex = -1;
configs.some((a,n) => userInput.every((u,i) => a[i] == u)?(inputIndex=n,true):false);
console.log(inputIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
var result = _.find(configs, function(t) {
  return _.isEqual(userInput, t);
});
```

If you need to know the index:

```
var index = -1;
_.some(configs, function(t, idx) {
  if (_.isEqual(userInput, t)) {
    index = idx;
    return true;
  }
});
// index = -1 if not found, else the first index of configs that matches the userInput
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be concerned about the place where there might be duplicates. If you can make a function that can test equality reliably then this is just a filter.

```
var matches = configs.filter(config => _.isEqual(config, userInput));
var match = matches[0];
```

If you wanted to invest into using a library more you could use something like [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find)

```
var match = _.find(configs, config => _.isEqual(config, userInput));
```